# What are some of the common Python design patterns for storing and refreshing google oauth2 credentials

Tags: python, oauth

I'm building one of my first Python apps and am looking for some advice understanding google oauth and related app design patterns.  My primary goal is to build an app that polls my Nest for data and learn to do so securely.  Using google's API and oauth2 Python libraries, I've successfully created a tiny Flask app that will return data from a google API along with an auth token + refresh token.  The core functions look something like this:

```
sdm = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
      API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)

response = sdm.api.endpoint.call(API_PARAMS)
```

This app uses the `client_secret.json` info generated during ouath ID creation.  However, in my travels across google's documentation and various tutorials I get the impression I should use the auth token (bearer token?) to make these API calls instead of `client_secrets.json`.

My original idea was to build one app that uses the `refresh_token` to refresh the auth_token and store it somewhere.  I would then have a second app that reads the auth_token and makes the API calls, stores data, etc.  In trying to create the first app that obtains and refreshes the auth token, I've created an app that can do both.

Building two functions (poll data and auth) seems like the right way to go.  It allows me to separate the token, refresh token and client_secrets and keep them in different places as the API polling function only needs to know the auth token.

My question is, am I over complicating things in trying to separate auth_refresh and api_calls in to separate apps?  What is the most common way to securely store and use oauth creds?  Where can I find more information on common google API + oauth design patterns?  Chances are I've read too many tutorials at once and have melted my brain in the google documentation labyrinth.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: [The docs for requests-oauthlib](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/real_world_example_with_refresh.html) have a pretty comprehensive example

Comment: The simple app referenced above is based on google's "Complete Example" in their API docs.    https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps#python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more perusing of the docs and stackoverflow code snippets I landed on the below using the google API and oauth Python libraries.  Separating these duties seems like the right way to go.  In theory you could accomplish the same using curl or the Python requests library.  This approach seemed "cleanest" to me.  Eye of the beholder and all that...

In any case, here are the core parts one would need to independently rotate and use a google api auth token in a back end process (here, specifically, I want to periodically poll my Nest and store the data).  It assumes you've already handled requesting client authorization and the google user has authorized the app.  The portion outlined here is mainly for using the credentials post authorization.

```
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google.auth.transport.requests
import googleapiclient.discovery


# the first function refreshes the auth token every hour and writes it to secrets storage
# it can access the more sensitive bits like refresh_token
credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
            token=TOKEN
            refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN,
            token_uri=TOKEN_URI,
            client_id=CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET
        )

# refresh the token
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(request)
TOKEN = credentials.token

write_to_secrets_store(TOKEN)


# the second function does the API call and related stuffs
# it can see the token but none of the sensitive bits like refresh_token and client_secret
credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(token=TOKEN)

# make an api call
sdm = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
            API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)

api_results = sdm.enterprises().structures().list(parent=ENTERPRISE_PARENT).execute()

do_stuff_with(api_results)
```